# Using gVIM as a replacement for Visual Studio

Tags: gvim, ide

Is there a good way to get gVim working as an IDE replacement?  I'm moreso looking for suggestions for Intellisense-type plugins...code completion...maybe easy directory browsing (other than the standard 'edit.' command).

I'm building embedded applications in C...so I have no need to incorporate any debugging elements, and for the build process I can just have a console window open to call my batch file whenever it is required (or if I could call it through some hotkey combination in gVIM...that would be awesome as well).

**edit**

Also, Find in Files would be a nice feature as well....say define my source code directory as the base and then recursively search all files for a keyword...not sure if this is possible as well or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up ctags to scan your code every e.g. 30 mins.

use Ctrl-] to jump to the definition of a function/variable.

user Ctrl-P while editing to complete a word.